# Combining nested query with boolean query in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-nested

I am trying to filter hotel rooms by price range in Elastic Search. The rooms have a default nightly price and also custom prices can be set for specific days.

I'm storing the `nightlyPrice` and a nested object for custom prices together with the dates. The mapping is smt. like:

```
{
  "adverts": {
    "mappings": {
      "advert": {
        "properties": {
          "nightlyPrice": {"type": "float"},
          "customPrices": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "date": {"type": "date"},
              "price": {"type": "float"}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For example I want to get the rooms within the price range of 100 and 200$ between the dates 1st and 7th of July.

So I came up with this logic:

1. Either `customPrices.date` must be between 2019-07-01 and 2019-07-07 and `customPrices.price` between 100 and 200.
2. or the `nightlyPrice` must be between 100 and 200 and no `customPrices.date` is set between 05 and 07 July.

However I couldn't be able to apply this logic to Elastic Search, nested objects / queries are kinda tricky I guess.

This is the final query I came up with:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "active"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "customPrices",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "date": {
                              "from": "2019-07-01",
                              "to": "2019-07-07"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "price": {
                              "from": 100,
                              "to": 200
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "nightlyPrice": {
                          "from": 100,
                          "to": 200
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "customPrices",
                        "query": {
                          "range": {
                            "customPrices.date": {
                              "from": "2019-07-01",
                              "to": "2019-07-07"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this query is if customPrices.date matches the date range it never matches the document no matter the price range is. I experimented with 1 - 100000$ price range and it still doesn't match.

Tried to use the explain API to understand why a specific document didn't match but   I don't understand it, it says `user requested match_none` query but there's this `should` query so it should match the nested query (first one):

```
{
  "_index": "adverts",
  "_type": "advert",
  "_id": "13867",
  "matched": false,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 0.0,
    "description": "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 0.0,
        "description": "no match on required clause (+(ToParentBlockJoinQuery (MatchNoDocsQuery(\"User requested \"match_none\" query.\")) (+nightlyPrice:[100.0 TO 200.0] -ToParentBlockJoinQuery (customListingPrices.date:[1561939200000 TO 1562543999999]))) #status:active",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 0.0,
            "description": "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
            "details": [
              {
                "value": 0.0,
                "description": "no match on required clause (ToParentBlockJoinQuery (MatchNoDocsQuery(\"User requested \"match_none\" query.\")) (+nightlyPrice:[100.0 TO 200.0] -ToParentBlockJoinQuery (customListingPrices.date:[1561939200000 TO 1562543999999])))",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 0.0,
                    "description": "No matching clauses",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "value": 0.0,
                "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
                "details": [
                  {
                    "value": 0.0,
                    "description": "# clause",
                    "details": []
                  },
                  {
                    "value": 1.0,
                    "description": "status:active",
                    "details": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 0.0,
        "description": "match on required clause, product of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 0.0,
            "description": "# clause",
            "details": []
          },
          {
            "value": 1.0,
            "description": "DocValuesFieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]",
            "details": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help or idea is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

If you closely look at the first `must` clause, it appears that you haven't mentioned the entire path of the field.

```
{  
   "range":{  
      "date":{               <-- must be "customPrices.date"
         "from":"2019-07-01",
         "to":"2019-07-07"
      }
   }
},
{  
   "range":{  
      "price":{             <-- must be "customPrices.price"
         "from":100,
         "to":200
      }
   }
}
```

Below is how the query should be and should work fine for your use case.

### Query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "filter":{  
            "term":{  
               "status":"active"
            }
         },
         "must":[  
            {  
               "bool":{  
                  "should":[  
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"customPrices",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "bool":{  
                                          "must":[  
                                             {  
                                                "range":{  
                                                   "customPrices.date":{  
                                                      "gte":"2019-07-01",
                                                      "lte":"2019-07-09"
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             },
                                             {  
                                                "range":{  
                                                   "customPrices.price":{  
                                                      "gte":100,
                                                      "lte":200
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             }
                                          ]
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        "bool":{  
                           "must":[  
                              {  
                                 "range":{  
                                    "nightlyPrice":{  
                                       "gte":100,
                                       "lte":200
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ],
                           "must_not":[  
                              {  
                                 "nested":{  
                                    "path":"customPrices",
                                    "query":{  
                                       "range":{  
                                          "customPrices.date":{  
                                             "gte":"2019-07-05",
                                             "lte":"2019-07-07"
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey @madpoet, did the above solve the issue you've had. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Curious why you have both a `should` and a `must` around the nested query. Surely a `must` is fine by itself?

Comment: Well, initially I thought about it but perhaps OP must have a much more complex query which he didn't reveal. I just shared with him the exact solution pertaining to the issue due to which he was stuck with.

Also it depends on the depth of the query, like what if he has multiple `should` and `must` clauses at **different depths**. Perhaps that is why I think he knows what he is doing and shared him solution where he got stuck with. I've seen much more complex queries at lot deeper levels and I'm gonna give him a benefit of doubt of it.